# What word describes ruthlessly energetic teens?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes teenagers who are ruthlessly energetic?  - I'm thinking of the word "Vibrant", but it doesn't fit well. The goal is to describe a group of teenagers who are partying nonstop.

I doubt the word should be positive. A negative can work.

A sentence with the word should go like this:

> Your approach to addressing those teenagers was not tactful enough, you spoke to them forcefully, and that's why they couldn't stop partying even after your warning. These are ______ teenagers and need to be addressed with care to get a good response from them.

Comment: Should it be a positive word or a negative word?

Comment: Are you simply looking for an ***intensifier*** to apply to the adjective ***energetic**?* (where ***ruthlessly*** doesn't really work). If so, please explain why you don't want to use a standard intensifier such as ***very, extremely, exceptionally, intensely,...*** If not, what additional meaning is the sought word supposed to confer on ***energetic***?

Comment: Delinquent? Irresponsible? Amoral? Hedonistic? Destructive? Wired? Drug-crazed? Nihilistic? Party-loving? Selfish? Thoughtless? Wild? Wolfish? Greedy? Nietzschean? Animalistic? Evil? Noisy? Try and be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this doesn't have the 'energetic' part of your request explicitly, it does have the 'wild' part of it. I'd like to suggest *rowdy*.

> If you’re rowdy, you’re loud and raucous. You’re disturbing the peace and somebody’s likely to ask you to quiet down.
>
> *adj.*: disturbing the public peace; loud and rough
>
> “rowdy teenagers” ([Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rowdy))
>
> noisy and seeming likely to become violent ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rowdy))
>
> behaving in a noisy rough way that is likely to cause arguments and fighting ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rowdy))

The example from Vocabulary.com actually uses 'teenagers,' and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rowdy%20teenagers%22&hl=en&gl=us&tbm=bks&ei=TXg9ZLjLGd6YptQPjuSHmAw&ved=0ahUKEwj4pa2nr7H-AhVejIkEHQ7yAcMQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22rowdy%20teenagers%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQIFi-D2DdEmgAcAB4AIAB4QKIAZYGkgEFMS4zLTKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books&safe=active&ssui=on) are a number of other instances of "rowdy teenagers" in books.

It also uses the word 'raucous,' which is relevant. Per [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/raucous), to be 'raucous' means that one is

> behaving in a very rough and noisy way

Answer (score 1):

One word (or rather phrase) would be **out of control,** [defined by TfD as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+control)

> Reckless or wild; in an unruly or unmanageable state or manner.

Comment: Rambunctious, perhaps.